# How to SQL format NUMBER data types to Numbers with Comma Separators in Toad for Oracle?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, relational-database, toad

I'm using Toad for Oracle.

I have a Schema called `SENSORMAINTAB`.
And my table of Interest is called `SENSOR_INSPECTIONS`.

The table has 2 Columns - `LOT_ID` (Data Type is `NUMBER`) and `INSPECTION_ID`. A truncated version of the Table is shown below:

| LOT_ID | INSPECTION_ID |
| --- | --- |
| 1402350701 | 49 |
| 1569638596 | 50 |
| 1569832145 | 51 |

I am looking for all `LOT_IDs` that have an `INSPECTION_ID` of `49`. Using the following Query:

`SELECT LOT_ID`

`FROM SENSORMAINTAB.SENSOR_INSPECTIONS`

`WHERE INSPECTION_ID = 49`

This returns me the following result.
|LOT_ID    |
|----------|
|1402350701|

Is there a way for me to format the `LOT_ID` Number with Comma Separators?
Like this:

| LOT_ID |
| --- |
| 1, 402, 350, 701 |